# Granting a SQL Server Login Access to a Database - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, authentication

I want to grant access to a database for a SQL Server login. I know about sp_grantdbaccess, however it is deprecated. What can I use instead and how can I check if the login does not already have access to the database?

Scenario: UserA creates database - in sys.database_principals I have an entry with name dbo and with the sid of UserA. I try to grant UserA permisions again: I try to do a select on sys.database_principals by name='UserA', however since name is dbo not UserA, I get an error - 'The login already has an account under a different user name.'. How can I determine if the user has database access without the sid?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want [CREATE USER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx)

e.g.

```
CREATE USER bobuser FOR LOGIN boblogin
```

The [sys.database_principals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) security catalog has a list of the database users, so you can ensure you don't already have one with that name.

Comment: If the user already has database access, it will return an error. How can I verify if the user has database access?

Comment: You could run a query like `if not exists(select * from sys.database_principals where name='bobuser') begin create user...` etc to see if it exists first

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a User in that database for the Login in question. To do that, use `Create User`. If you want to determine if the user already exists, you can use `sys.database_principals` catalog view by filtering for `type = 'U'`. If you want to determine if a given user is already in a role, you can use `sys.database_role_members`.